# Upload Laravel to shared hosting issue

Tags: laravel

I uploaded my laravel project to a free hosting, everything seems to be working fine until i tried to upload an image into the `storage` folder, using this line of code `$newLeague->logo = $request->logo->store('images');` the path is stored in the database but the image isn't uploaded.

Filesystems.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default filesystem disk that should be used
    | by the framework. The "local" disk, as well as a variety of cloud
    | based disks are available to your application. Just store away!
    |
    */

    'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Cloud Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Many applications store files both locally and in the cloud. For this
    | reason, you may specify a default "cloud" driver here. This driver
    | will be bound as the Cloud disk implementation in the container.
    |
    */

    'cloud' => env('FILESYSTEM_CLOUD', 's3'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Filesystem Disks
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure as many filesystem "disks" as you wish, and you
    | may even configure multiple disks of the same driver. Defaults have
    | been setup for each driver as an example of the required options.
    |
    | Supported Drivers: "local", "ftp", "s3", "rackspace"
    |
    */

    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        ],

    ],

];
```

Comment: check permissions

Comment: I changed the permissions to drwxrwxrwx but i didn't fix it :/

Comment: which driver are you using ?

Comment: am using mysql driver

Comment: For as far as I know, you can't upload images to the storage folder with the `->store()` method. That places them in the public folder.

Comment: Yes i'm aware of that, i already created the storage link ... it used to work on local but when i hosted the app it didn't.

Comment: What "the storage link"?

Comment: `php artisan storage link`, that create the storage folder in the public folder where files are placed with the `->store()` method

Comment: Hmm. Do your uploads get stored in the `root/storage/public` folder? Maybe the symlink just doesn't work and the rest is okay.

Comment: there's no public folder in the storage folder

Answer (score 0):

check and change permissions to folders 
to 07777 mark all checkboxes.

Comment: I actually changed them but it didn't fixed it, am i supposed to make some changes on the filesystems.php or .env files ?